# Displaying waveform in delphi7 or component to do it?

Tags: delphi, delphi-7, waveform

Recently i'm working my project to make an audio watermarking, so far so good then i came to an idea to show a waveform in my program created with delphi 7.I have an  array contain sample data of the right and left channel of the audio stored in double, i read some random article if i use the TImage to do this still i can't display the full waveform because the size were too big to display in it. Does anyone know how i can trick this and do it in a simple way or is there any component that can take input of an array then display a waveform from it?

Answer (score 1):

You can try WavForm
http://delphi.icm.edu.pl/ftp/d40free/wavviewer.zip

the author is unknown, but youi have the source to adapt it to your needs or fix eventual bugs